# How to find all roadway intersections from a large dataset of linestrings stored in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, postgis, geography

I have 40,000 road linestrings stored in a BigQuery table and I want to find all of the unique intersections for them. I found out how to do this in postGIS here (https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20835/identifying-road-intersections-using-postgis/151277#151277) but I can't use this code in BigQuery because I can't group by a geography.

```
SELECT      
    ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom),
    Count(Distinct a.gid)
FROM
    roads as a,
    roads as b
WHERE
    ST_Touches(a.geom, b.geom)
    AND a.gid != b.gid
GROUP BY
    ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom)



  [1]: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20835/identifying-road-intersections-using-postgis/151277#151277
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm missing why you need to aggregate the results:

```
SELECT ST_Intersection(r1.geom, r2.geom)
FROM roads r1 JOIN
     roads r2
     ON ST_Touches(r1.geom, r2.geom) AND
        r1.gid < r2.gid
```

Comment: oh nice, I couldn't figure out how to do it. I was trying to adapt the postgis code. Seems like your way is better. Thank you.

Comment: One oddity I found was duplicate points with your code. I know it's hard for you to diagnose without the data or more context. But my original code found 42139 intersections, with yours I found 63595. Then I ran a select distict with yours and found 40035 uniques.

This is likely caused by oddities in my data but I wanted to throw it out there

Comment: @KylePennell . . . Interesting.  That means that different road pairs can intersect with the same set of points, which seems unlikely to me.  Is it possible that roads might be duplicated in your data set.  Here in the US, for instance, a Federal highway could also be a State road and have two different numbers.

Comment: That's a great suggestion of what to check for. Anyway, thank you very much for the nice succinct way to find intersections in a bunch of linestrings

Comment: If you do need to remove the duplicates, use this pattern:
`WITH geog_table AS (<your query here>)
SELECT any_value(geom), count(*) 
FROM geog_table GROUP BY ST_AsText(geom)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use most of the same answer but just need to parse the geography as text in a CTE and then convert it back to a geography.

```
with geomandcount as (
SELECT      
    st_astext(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom)) as the_geom,
    Count(Distinct a.geoid) as count
    
FROM
    `roadways_table` as a,
    `roadways_table` as b
WHERE
    ST_intersects(a.geom, b.geom)
    AND a.geoid != b.geoid

group by st_astext(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom))
)

select st_geogfromtext(the_geom) as the_geom, count 

from geomandcount
```

Comment: leaving this answer as a hope that it can help someone else, but if I'm breaking some stackoverflow, let me know.

Comment: I think you can avoid ST_GeogFromText here using ANY_VALUE function:
`select any_value(g), count(*)
from geog_table
group by st_astext(g)`